# Solve for the total every transaction is going in. (Google chart)

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, charts

I have a chart where I need to calculate the amount I'm earning as time goes by. In this chart, I  have the amount (red line). My target is to calculate the total of every transaction that is going in. My current code is not working properly because when the time is **18:26:23** it is **1000 amount** when it is **18:26:24**, it is still **1000**... It should be **2000**. **It should solve for the sum over time.** I have provided my codes below and a screenshot of my current system and my target. Thank you in advance.

[image]
[image]

**Views**:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- LINE CHART -->
            <div class="card card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Stats Per Day</h3>

                <div class="card-tools">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse" style="width:30%;">
                    <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="chart">
                  <div id="wholechart" style="min-height: 250px; height: 250px; max-height: 250px; max-width: 100%;"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            
                   
   </div>
```

**Ajax**:

```
 function sampleeesasw(){
  
   $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '<?=site_url('report/datas')?>',
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(result) { 
                
                 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
                    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){drawChart(result);});
                
                
                
                       function drawChart(result) {
                    
                          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                          data.addColumn('string', 'req');
                           data.addColumn('number', 'total');
                            data.addColumn('number', 'amount');
                         
                          
                          var dataArray =[];
                            $.each(result,function(i,obj){
                            dataArray.push([obj.req,parseInt(obj.total),parseInt(obj.amount)]);
                            
                            });
                            
                            data.addRows(dataArray );

                    
                           var options = {
        seriesType: "line",
 
    };
                    
                    
                        
                    
                          var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('wholechart')).
                          
                    //       Line,Bar,Area,Clomun,pie
                    
                         draw(data, {curveType: "function",
    vAxes: {0: {logScale: false},
            1: {logScale: false, maxValue: 2}},
    series:{
       0:{targetAxisIndex:0},
       1:{targetAxisIndex:1},
       2:{targetAxisIndex:1}}}
          );
                         
                        }
                
                 }
                
                });


}

    
     setInterval(function(){ 
sampleeesasw()
},1000);
```

**Controller**:

```
public function datas(){
        $data= $this->reports->wholedatachart();
        
        foreach($data as $row){
            $data['req']=$row['req'];
            $data['amount']=$row['amount'];
            $data['total']=$row['total'];
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
        
    }
```

Model:

```
  function wholedatachart(){
        
        
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT timeProcess as 'req', transID as 'total', amount as 'amount' FROM tbl_transaction");
        return $query->result_array();
        
        
    }
```

Comment: can you post also your data structure

Comment: https://prnt.sc/13twypr Is this what you meant? I'm sorry. I'm newbie. Thank you.

Comment: so you want it to be incremented and show total amount each new data ( eg. 18:26:23 will show 1000 and on 18:26:24 will show 2000 ) or total overall today ?,

Comment: eg. 18:26:23 will show 1000 and on 18:26:24 will show 2000 )  <<< this one

Comment: Hi, transaction are already store in db or they are simultaneously inserting in other part of code and on interval you are fetching them ?

Comment: Hello, It is already stored in DB.

Comment: So, you are just fetching all records and adding them in chart ? Why need interval then ?

Comment: My bad, I am fetching them on interval for example for 1 min = all transactions + another 1 min = overall transactions and so on... I made a mistake, that was my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do calculation part inside your `drawChart` function. Inside that function you can simply total value of amount then , save it in some variable and pass it to your `dataArray.push(..)`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//suppose data look like this..
var result = [{
  "req": "1",
  "amount": 2000,
  "total": 1000
},{
  "req": "2",
  "amount": 1000,
  "total": 1000
},{
  "req": "3",
  "amount": 1000,
  "total": 1000
}]

function sampleeesasw() {

  /*$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {*/

  google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    drawChart(result);
  });
  function drawChart(result) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'req');
  data.addColumn('number', 'total');
  data.addColumn('number', 'amount');


  var dataArray = [];
  var total=0 //intialze..
  $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
  total +=parseInt(obj.amount)//add on each iteration
    dataArray.push([obj.req, parseInt(obj.total), parseInt(total)]); //add value here ..
  });

  data.addRows(dataArray);


  var options = {
    seriesType: "line",

  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('wholechart')).draw(data, {
    curveType: "function",
    vAxes: {
      0: {
        logScale: false
      },
      1: {
        logScale: false,
        maxValue: 2
      }
    },
    series: {
      0: {
        targetAxisIndex: 0
      },
      1: {
        targetAxisIndex: 1
      },
      2: {
        targetAxisIndex: 1
      }
    }
  });

}
  /* }
  });*/

}





setInterval(function() {
  sampleeesasw()
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <!-- LINE CHART -->
  <div class="card card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h3 class="card-title">Stats Per Day</h3>

      <div class="card-tools">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse" style="width:30%;">
                    <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                  </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="chart">
        <div id="wholechart" style="min-height: 250px; height: 250px; max-height: 250px; max-width: 100%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-body -->
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Hello, Swati. will definitely try this tomorrow morning. (Because I'm not at home right now) I hope you can wait for my reply. 

Thank you and I do really appreciated it.

Comment: Hello, Swati. I did your suggestion also. The only thing that happens is that it counts the per transaction, not the total amount itself.  Please see this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/1402byz

Comment: :P which value you need total of `obj.total` or `obj.amount` ?

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't make things clear, I'm aiming for obj.amount.

Comment: so you need to total values of `obj.amount` and show in place of which label ? Sorry for making you confuse :)

Comment: also in your screenshot you have not change `dataArray.push([obj.req, parseInt(obj.total), parseInt(total)]);` look closesly to my code. I am passing `total` as last parameter

Comment: Wow, Swati. Thank you very much. I do really appreciate your effort in helping me. Thank you so much again.

Comment: Glad i was able to help to you  :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this one, you need to increment the amount of each data, you can use a temporary variable and increment all the amount.

I edited the answer sorry my bad.

change your controller to

```
public function datas(){
        $data= $this->reports->wholedatachart();
        $tempAmount = 0;
        foreach($data as $row){

            $tempAmount = $tempAmount + $row['amount'];

            $output[]=array(
            'req'        => $timeline['time'],
            'amount'    => $tempAmount,
            'amount'    => $row['amount'],
            );
        
 

        }
        echo json_encode($output);
}
```

if you want to add the total also you can do the same thing

Comment: Hello, I tried it and nothing changed, It is still the same 
https://prnt.sc/13u1o52 << Please see this. Thank you

Comment: Hello, Daffa. I did what you suggested and this is what happened.  The graph disappeared and nothing changes. https://prnt.sc/13zzwkq

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not able to help you, glad you found your answer, thanks for the feedback